# Offset Height Parameter in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert an Excel formula into VBA and I'm having some difficulties with the Offset conversion. The formula is being used to perform a VLookup on filtered data.

The Excel formula is:

`=VLOOKUP(G4 & "",IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(D2:D36419,ROW(D2:D36419)-ROW(D2),0,1))>0,D2:E36419),2,0)`

My current VBA code is:

```
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(key & "", _
    IIf(Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, _
    ws.Range("D2:D36419").Offset(ws.Range("D2:D36419").Row - ws.Range("D2").Row, 0)) > 0, ws.Range("D2:E36419"), 0), 2, 0)
```

I need some way to include the Offset height parameter (1). Any ideas?

Note: I've tried

```
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(key & "", _
    IIf(Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, _
    ws.Range("D2:D36419").Offset(ws.Range("D2:D36419").Row - ws.Range("D2").Row, 0).Resize(1)) > 0, ws.Range("D2:E36419"), 0), 2, 0)
```

without success.

Comment: There's more than likely a different way to do it in VBA without the use of formula - something likes `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.  What is the formula meant to do?

Comment: I have a large table that I will filter with user data (device and facility are the two filter options). The formula allows me to perform a VLookup on the full range of data but will just look at the visible, filtered cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim FindValue As Range
    Dim ReturnValue As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        'Note: I've set this one row above your search range so D2 is first cell that's looked at.
        Set SearchRange = .Range("D1:D36419").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        
        Set FindValue = SearchRange.Find(What:=.Range("G4"), After:=SearchRange.Cells(1), _
                                         LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                                         
        If Not FindValue Is Nothing Then
            Set ReturnValue = FindValue.Offset(, 1)
            MsgBox ReturnValue & " found in " & ReturnValue.Address, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to say this is the answer because SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) is giving me the table I need to perform my searches. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes find it hard finding the 'correct' VBA alternative to some of the Excel functions. And resort to this technique `range("C1").value="=A1+B1"` where you put the Excel formula in speech marks.

Sometimes I would need to know the value of `A1+B1` for an if statement, but wouldn't need the total of `A1+B1` being displayed. So I may do `Range("AAA1481").value = "=A1+B1"`. It is unlikely AAA1481 will have any actual data in it. It should be out of sight and mind.

And then run a if statement such as -

```
If Range("AAA1481").value > 1000 then
msgbox ("above 1000")
end if 
Range("AAA1481").clearcontents
```

Finding the correct VBA way of writing `A1+B1` probably isn't too hard but I find my technique is a godsend when dealing with messy formulas like -

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MAX(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"L",".4"),"M",".3"),"S",".2"),"R",".1"))),".4","L"),".3","M"),".2","S"),".1","R")
```

Comment: The subtotal function is just being used to determine if a cell is visible or not. I don't think I actually want the summed value.